# Magento 2 Backup Restoration Issue on AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: magento2, aws, backup

I am experiencing an issue restoring a Magento 2 backup on an AWS EC2 instance. After successfully restoring the backup, when I try to access the site via the EC2 instance's IP address, I encounter a "Error 503 Backend fetch failed" error, indicating an issue with the Varnish cache server.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for these you can check with the:

```
-> Varnish issue contact your server administrator
-> Check varnish configuration in the env.php
-> Check the credentials of the Varnish
```

It is confirmed that it's the issue of the varnish side.